# How do I add a primary key to a mysql table as the first column

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE CustomerInfo ADD OrgID smallInt not null first primary key(OrgID);
```

Comment: What do you mean by *first column* columns don't have (or need) any specific order.

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 1):

2 errors, FIRST has to be after column definition and you don't need to specify the column name in the primary key clause

```
ALTER TABLE CustomerInfo ADD OrgID smallInt not null primary key first;
```

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 1):

We both forgot "AUTO_INCREMENT"
This worked:

ALTER TABLE CustomerInfo ADD OrgID smallInt  not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key first;

Comment: Not me , auto_increment is not a requirement for a primary key.